# Get already started appointments using EWS

Tags: c#, ssis, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have implemented an SSIS package retrieving outlook calendar items including recurring ones. The problem is that I have to use:

```
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1));
```

because ItemView does not expand recurring items.

My issue is that I'm actually stuck getting appintments which have already started. The above parameters select only those which will be from now on and as soon the "now" is in the past they will not be retrieved.

The problem is that I cannot use SearchFilters with CalendarView (only with ItemView).

Does anybody have a hint how I can get also the already started appointments?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any idea :)

Comment: Are you searching for a build in solution? I can only think of iterating through every search result (with "startDate" set to -12 hours from now or something), get the end date and compare it to DateTime.Now.

Comment: Hi Istanfin

Thank you for your answer. Yes this was also what I was thinkin about. It seems that there is no other possibiltiy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue as suggested by Istafin, obviously the only way actually. thanks!